# Advanced Datagrid SummaryField Treats XML Data as String

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, advanceddatagrid

I have an advanced datagrid, with the grouping collection attached to an XMLListCollection.

I tried to perform a SummaryOperation, but always ends up getting 0 (zero) on the SummaryRow as it seems the data is being treated as string, instead of numeric.

Is there a way to force the SummaryField2 object to treat the data as numeric rather than string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The older SummaryField has a summaryFunction property that does what you need. You could probably also write your own SummaryOperation that takes XML into account.

Comment: Would you be able to show some example code to write a custom function for the summaryOperation?

Comment: No, I haven't created one, but if you look at the docs for SummaryField2, it tells you what interface you need to implement, and you can probably look at one of the existing operations to see what the implementation should (roughly) look like.  You will probably find you can just extend the one that's closest to your need and add support for XML.